# Powershell SQL JobServer Start Run Date or Last Run Outcome

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-3.0

Folks, Hope you are all well.

I am trying to find a PowerShell example which can help me to find out if a backup job failed to start or did not fail to start i.e. started.

So far I can find out the job name by using Name method, whether the job is enabled or not through the IsEnabled function, as well as see the last run outcome of a job through the LastRUnOutcome function (if = 1 i.e. if its successful print "Successful" or 1 else its "Failed").

The issue is that with the above we don't know whether the job executed or not. So for example when the job did not start we would still get back a result of successful (i.e. enable) but a successful enabled job doesn't mean it is a successful started job and succssful completed job.

In terms of code, where I am failing (and lacking powershell oomphh) is when I try to pull in the start run date of the job i.e. step 2 above 'job started' or any other function closely related such as last run date or last run date's time.

The Environment setup - my computer local:
PowerShell V3.0
SQL 2005
.Net 2 - disabled under Services
.Net 4 - not running, automatic under Services

On server local services:
.Net 2.0 & 3.0
MSSQLSERVER
SQL SERVER AGENT (MSQLSERVER)

On server proper - Server Managment tool:
4.0

Object Library:

```
# Create an SMO Server object
$srv = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" $sqlserver;
# Create jobs variable from object
$jobsHistory=$srv.JobServer.Jobs
# Create an SMO connection to the instance for job history methods
$jobHistoryFilter = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.JobHistoryFilter" $sqlserver;
```

Idea trying:

```
$jobName = $job.Name; #jobs name
$jobEnabled = $job.IsEnabled; #step 1 job is enabled
$jobLastRunDate = $jobsHistoryFilter.StartRunDate  #step 2 job started date (result of executing backup i.e. if date was today it successfully started)
#$executionResult #step 3 job result(post execution result/did it backup or not, i.e. successful back or not)
#$jobLastRunOutcome = $job.LastRunOutcome; #step 4 jobs last run result
```

From the above where I am I going wrong and what and/or how many steps do I need to accomplish the results of 1. job enabled, 2. job started result (start executed), and 3. job result - successful or failed (post start execution). Are three steps enough? Or do I need 4?

I have a feeling it's to do with my environment and maybe functions in SQL2005 not compatible with PowerShell 3.0.

Please explain why you are giving me the functions you are i.e. their usefulness in forming my answer.

All help much appreciated as this bugging me!

The whole code is this below, anything outside of this and your being too nosy ;):

```
# Load SMO extension
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") | Out-Null;

# Get List of sql servers to check
$sqlservers = Get-Content $sqlserverlistpath;

""
"---------DAILY CHECKLIST AUTOMATION----------"
"---------------SAM v1.0.5---------------"
"----------------15th Jan 2013---------------"
""

"----------SQL SERVER & BACKUP CHECK----------"
""

#output some information onto our excel sheet

$intRow = 0
$intRow = $intRow + 1
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1) = "Daily Checklist for system:"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2) =  $systemname
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2).Font.Bold = $True
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1).Font.Bold = $True
            $intRow = $intRow + 1

$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1) = "Date:"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2) = $date
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2).Font.Bold = $True
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1).Font.Bold = $True
            $intRow = $intRow + 1
            $intRow = $intRow + 1

$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1) = "SQL JOBS"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1).Font.Bold = $True
$intRow = $intRow + 1
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1) = "Servername"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1).Font.Bold = $True
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2) = "Job Name"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2).Font.Bold = $True
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,3) = "Enabled"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,3).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,3).Font.Bold = $True

$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,4) = "Last Ran Date"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,4).Font.Bold = $True
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,4).Interior.ColorIndex = 19


$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,5) = "Status"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,5).Font.Bold = $True
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,5).Interior.ColorIndex = 19

#added columns to record check person, date, actions
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,6).Font.Bold = $True
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,6).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,6) = "Checked By"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,7).Font.Bold = $True
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,7).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,7) = "Date"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,8).Font.Bold = $True
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,8).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,8) = "Actions (if any)"



$WorkBook = $Sheet.UsedRange

$intRow = $intRow + 1


# Loop through each sql server from sqlservers.txt
foreach($sqlserver in $sqlservers)
{
      # Create an SMO Server object
      #$srv = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" $sqlserver;


      $srv = new-object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -ArgumentList $sqlserver
      $srv.JobServer.Jobs | where {$_.IsEnabled} | Select Name, HasSchedule, LastRunDate, LastRunOutcome



      # Jobs counts
      $totalJobCount = $srv.JobServer.Jobs.Count;
      $failedCount = 0;
      $successCount = 0;
      $notRunOrNotExistCount = 0;

      Write-Host -ForegroundColor white "=========================================================================================";
      Write-Host -ForegroundColor white "$sqlserver | $sqlserver | $sqlserver | $sqlserver | $sqlserver | $sqlserver ";
      Write-Host -ForegroundColor white "=========================================================================================";  
      ""


# For each jobs on the server
foreach($job in $srv.JobServer.Jobs)
{
            # Default write colour
            $colour = "Green";
            $jobName = $job.Name;
            $jobEnabled = $job.IsEnabled;                      #step 1 job is enabled
           # $jobLastRunDate = $srv.JobServer.Jobs.LastRunDate; #step 2 job started date (result of executing backup i.e. if date was today it successfully started)
            #$executionResult =                                #step 3 job result  (post execution result/did it backup or not, i.e. successful back or not)
            #$jobLastRunOutcome = $job.LastRunOutcome;         #step 4 job result  what this produce?






            # Set write text to red for Failed jobs
          # if($jobLastRunOutcome -eq "Failed")
          # {
               #    $colour = "Red";
               #    $failedCount += 1;

                   #write status
                #   $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2) = $jobname
               #    $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,6) = "Failed"
               #    $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,6).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

               #    $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,3) = $jobEnabled

           # }#otherwise it is successful
          # if ($jobLastRunOutcome -eq "Succeeded")
           # {
               #   $successCount += 1;

                  #write status
                #  $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2) = $jobname
                #  $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,5) = "Succeeded"
                #  $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,5).Interior.ColorIndex = 4

                #  $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,3) = $jobEnabled

           # }#otherwise it has failed to start running
           # elseif($jobEnabled -eq $FALSE) #iffalse
           # {


             #     $notRunOrNotExistCount += 1;

                  #write status
              #    $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2) = $jobname
              #    $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,3) = "Not Started"
              #    $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,3).Interior.ColorIndex = 46

              #    $colour = "Red";

              #    $failedCount += 1;
               #   $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,5) = "Failed"
              #    $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,5).Interior.ColorIndex = 3


           if($job.IsEnabled -and $job.HasSchedule)  # }elseif($job.IsEnabled -and $job.HasSchedule) #$jobEnabled = 1) #true)
            {

                  $Name = $job.Name
                  $LastRunOutcome = $job.LastRunOutcome
                  $LastRunDate = $job.LastRunDate

                  #$notRunOrNotExistCount += 1;


                  #write status
                 # $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2) = $jobname

                  #Enabled
                  #$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,3) = "Started" #$jobEnabled
                 # $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,3).Interior.ColorIndex = 4

                  #LastRunDate
                  $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,4) = "$LastRunDate"
                  $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,4).Interior.ColorIndex = 4



                 # $successCount += 1;

                  #status
                 # $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,5) = "Succeeded"
                #  $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,5).Interior.ColorIndex = 4

                  #checked by
                  #$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,6) = "SAM"
                #  $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,6).Interior.ColorIndex = 20

                  #$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,3) = $jobEnabled 

            }


            Write-Host -ForegroundColor $colour "SERVER = $sqlserver JOB = $jobName ENABLED = $jobEnabled LASTRUNDATE = $LastRunDate LASTRUN = $jobLastRunOutcome";
            $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1) = $sqlserver

            #give the cells we type into some colour

            Write-Output "$Name,   $LastRunOutcome,   $LastRunDate"

            $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,7).Interior.ColorIndex = 20
            $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,8).Interior.ColorIndex = 20

            $intRow = $intRow + 1

      }

      # Writes a summary for each SQL server
      Write-Host -ForegroundColor white "=========================================================================================";
      Write-Host -ForegroundColor white "$sqlserver total jobs = $totalJobCOunt, success count $successCount, failed jobs = $failedCount.";
      Write-Host -ForegroundColor white "=========================================================================================";     
}
```

Comment: Resources: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7b8d1a00-8609-40ff-9fff-e8d14becb982/invalid-cast-of-same-types?forum=winserverpowershell http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.jobserver%28v=sql.90%29.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.jobserver.jobs%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer this myself after 24hours.

All I did is utilise the same object class and a method available with this same class then add a new variable and call it:

```
 #Create an SMO Server object
 $srv = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" $sqlserver;
```

And add one new variable:

```
 $jobLastRunDate = $job.LastRunDate;
```

Call it:

```
#write status
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,4) = "$jobLastRunDate"
```

I can now also,if I want, have it side by side with a result status as so:

```
 #write status
    $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,4) = "$jobLastRunDate"
    $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,5) = "Succeeded"
```

Or go a step better and match the last run date's time with the set run time of the check, if it ran at the same time, then it is successful.

```
#find the execution time of check in SQL Server
$setExecutionTimeofCheck = $someServerObjectofExecutionSetTime


#write status
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,4) = "$jobLastRunDate"

if($jobLastRunDate => $setExecutionTimeofCheck)
{
    $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,5) = "Succeeded"
}
```

But looks like am trying to over complicate it as the current results I get are below and they run at different set times!

```
DB backup           1 01/30/2014 23:00:00
DB backup           2 01/26/2014 06:00:00
History             1 01/31/2014 02:00:00
Transaction backup    1 01/31/2014 13:00:00
```

That's for another day I take it folks? ;)

Thank you very much Bruce. And everyone else!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'm following what you're after.  The LastRunDate is the last time the job executed and the LastRunOutcome shows if it succedded the last time it ran.  If you just want a quick report for enabled jobs this will list them.  I added HasSchedule since a job can be enabled but unscheduled.

```
$srv = new-object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -ArgumentList $sqlserver
$srv.JobServer.Jobs | where {$_.IsEnabled} | Select Name, HasSchedule, LastRunDate, LastRunOutcome
```

After reading your comments I think you might want to use a foreach to loop through the jobs one at a time.

```
$srv = new-object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -ArgumentList $sqlserver
$srv.JobServer.Jobs | where {$_.IsEnabled} | Select Name, HasSchedule, LastRunDate, LastRunOutcome | `
foreach { $Name = $_.Name; $LastRunOutcome = $_.LastRunOutcome; $LastRunDate = $_.LastRunDate; `
          Write-Output "$Name,   $LastRunOutcome,   $LastRunDate" }
```

Or in a more readable formant.

```
foreach ($job in $srv.JobServer.Jobs) {
   if ($job.IsEnabled -and $job.HasSchedule) {
      $Name = $job.Name
      $LastRunOutcome = $job.LastRunOutcome
      $LastRunDate = $job.LastRunDate
      Write-Output "$Name,   $LastRunOutcome,   $LastRunDate"
   }
}
```

Comment: What you are doing is a select statement to view statuses, they are now held in the memory, but how would I translate that data held in the memory into a variable? At the moment I am using what you gave above then adding:

Comment: $jobLastRunDate = $srv.JobServer.Jobs.LastRunDate;

Comment: And finally adding this to pull through to the spreadsheet:                                                                                                                                                                                                       #LastRunDate
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,4) = $jobLastRunDate

Comment: And no luck, any other ideas? Is Powershell 3 compatible with my version of SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, I was on V3 yesterday connecting to SQL 2005 when I originally answered.  Today I'm on V2 but still hitting the same SQL Server.  Hopefully the addition to my answer will help.

Comment: Thanks for your update Bruce. Gave it a shot but no data is even brought back to the shell through the write-output variables, which also means no data will come in the spreadsheet.

Comment: So the select in the original answer shows data but the foreach additions don't?  Very strange, everything I've posted works for me.  I'm out of ideas.  Good luck.

Comment: Both the select in the orignal and the foreach show nothing. I'll give it another try. Thanks so far though! You're great.

Comment: Now I don't get anything back, what I am going to do is revert back to original code and findout why can I cannot add the last run cmd or last run date cmd to my code? All you pro's wake up and give us a one sentence answer please! :)

Comment: It could my other surrounding code, but I made sure to uncomment it and just leave class, object and variable definitions, so basically what you have given me above...

Comment: You are going straight to the job and not using that JobHistoryFilter in your original code correct?

Comment: Thanks Bruce, I waould yes, I am going straight to the code and not using the JobHistoryFilter in my edit above.

Comment: I have added the whole code in my original code, maybe this can help you see where I am going wrong.